# One Thread doesn't start in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, input

I am creating a Server/Client in Python and I am quite new to Threading, so I might be misunderstanding something. In my client class I have different threads for different tasks, such as: one thread for handling listening for packages and one thread for spamming the server with automated incremented messages.

Now i want to create a function where i can also input my own messages and send them to the server. However the thread for this doesn't even start, and I am not sure what i am doing wrong. All the other threads are working fine

The function:

`def send_user_input():
    print('USER INPUT THREAD RUNNING')
    while True:
        global msg_counter
        message = input('Type in your message: ')
        msg_counter += 1
        sendedmessage = message + ' #' + str(msg_counter)
        print('Sending: ' + sendedmessage)
        sock.sendto(sendedmessage.encode('utf-8'), server_address)`

The thread start:

```
    # Threads to start
    thread = Thread(target=package_listener)
    thread.start()
    thread3 = Thread(target=send_packages())
    thread3.start()
    thread4 = Thread(target=send_user_input())
    thread4.start()
```

Comment: You're called `send_packages()` instead of passing a reference to the function `send_packages`

Comment: Hallo Peter, i am not sure what you mean, the function i am trying to start is  def send_user_input():

Comment: You should pass the function to ‘Thread’ and it will call it. You are passing the result of calling the function, instead of the actual function.